# How to fix Rust error "value used here after move"?

Tags: rust, clone, ownership, borrowing

This is my Cargo.toml.

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["test <test@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.3"
walkdir = "2.3.1"
```

This is my main.rs.

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::Error;
use std::path::Path;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() {
    for entry in WalkDir::new(".").max_depth(1) {
        if &entry.unwrap().path().strip_prefix(".\\").unwrap().to_str().unwrap() == &"src" {
            println!("{:#?}", "Yes, it's src!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code could run without any issues. However, when I modify the code like the follow:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::Error;
use std::path::Path;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

fn main() {
    for entry in WalkDir::new(".").max_depth(1) {
        if &entry.unwrap().path().strip_prefix(".\\").unwrap().to_str().unwrap() == &"src" {
            println!("{:#?}", "Yes, it's src!!!");
        }

        if &entry.unwrap().path().strip_prefix(".\\").unwrap().to_str().unwrap() == &"target" {
            println!("{:#?}", "Yes, it's target!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

I got the error "value used here after move", which means the `&entry.unwrap()` in the second `if` is using moved value. My idea is to clone `entry` in the first `if` then `unwrap`. But there is no `clone()` method on it. How can I make this code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Result::unwrap` consumes the result object, moving the entry out of the `Result` and into the return value.

Either unwrap once and store the resulting object in a variable (`let entry = entry.unwrap();`) or use `Result::as_ref` to borrow the object inside of the `Result` (`entry.as_ref().unwrap().path()...`)